# Extract hourly max/min/median values with timestamp in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe with temperature measurements every 10 minutes. The measurements were taken at different locations (named as 'LCZ'), with for each location the values in a different column.

This is part of my dataframe: (it also contains missing values NA)

```
 Time `LCZ 3-2` `LCZ 3-10` `LCZ 6-1` `LCZ 6-9` `LCZ 9-4`


               <dttm>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2017-08-26 17:00:00      27.5       27.5      27.5      27.0      27.0
 2 2017-08-26 17:10:00      27.5       27.0      27.5      27.0      27.0
 3 2017-08-26 17:20:00      27.5       27.0      27.0      27.0      27.0
 4 2017-08-26 17:30:00      27.0       26.5      27.0      26.5      26.5
 5 2017-08-26 17:40:00      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.5
 6 2017-08-26 17:50:00      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.0      26.5
 7 2017-08-26 18:00:00      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.5
 8 2017-08-26 18:10:00      27.0       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.0
 9 2017-08-26 18:20:00      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0
10 2017-08-26 18:30:00      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0
```

I want for each location or column to calculate the hourly min/max/median temperature and in addition for the hourly min/max also the timestamp from the original data at which the min/max respectively occured.

Is this possible with R?

I tried already various functions.

`group_by` allowed me to calculate min/max for each column but without timestamps. `period.apply` also allowed me to calculate min/max/median but only for one column. 
Also `aggregate()` didn't lead to any succes.

I'm learning in R, but didn't came close to a solution on this problem.

This website has helped me with various problems, but I'm really stuck on this one. Can someone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you define an hour?

Comment: An hour as the summary of the values for 17:10, 17:20,...,17:50, the same for 18:10, 18:20,...,18:50 and so on

Comment: @M95 It would help if you can include format for your desired output in your question. Thanks

Comment: So for each hour, you want 15 values = 5 cols x 3 stats?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure what output to expect, but this answers my needs. Thank you for your answers! And also for the additional explanation in your answer which learned me to understand again a bit more in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `floor_date` from the [lubridate](/questions/tagged/lubridate) package to create a new column `Time2` to show the hourly information. If this is not the way you want to define the hourly grouping, you can also try `round_date` or `ceiling_date`. After that, we can use `gather` from the [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr) package to convert the data frame from wide format to long format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Time = ymd_hms(Time),
         Time2 = floor_date(Time, unit = "hour")) %>%
  gather(LCZ, Value, starts_with("LCZ")) %>%
  group_by(Time2, LCZ)
```

After that, we can summarize the data by `LCZ` and `Time2`.

```
dat3 <- dat2 %>%
  summarise(Min = min(Value, na.rm = TRUE),
            Max = max(Value, na.rm = TRUE),
            Median = median(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat3
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    Time2               LCZ        Min   Max Median
#    <dttm>              <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.10  26.0  27.5   26.8
#  2 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2   26.5  27.5   27.2
#  3 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.6.1   26.5  27.5   27.0
#  4 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.6.9   26.0  27.0   26.8
#  5 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.9.4   26.5  27.0   26.8
#  6 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.3.10  26.0  26.5   26.2
#  7 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.3.2   26.5  27.0   26.5
#  8 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.6.1   26.5  26.5   26.5
#  9 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.6.9   26.5  26.5   26.5
# 10 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.9.4   26.0  26.5   26.0
```

If you want, we can create binary value to indicate if the value is minimum, maximum, or median as follows. This format is useful when you further want to filter the data frame.

```
dat4 <- dat2 %>%
  mutate(Min = (Value == min(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) + 0L,
         Max = (Value == max(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) + 0L,
         Median = (Value == median(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) + 0L) %>%
  ungroup()
dat4
# # A tibble: 50 x 7
#    Time                Time2               LCZ     Value   Min   Max Median
#    <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>   <dbl> <int> <int>  <int>
#  1 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2  27.5     0     1      0
#  2 2017-08-26 17:10:00 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2  27.5     0     1      0
#  3 2017-08-26 17:20:00 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2  27.5     0     1      0
#  4 2017-08-26 17:30:00 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2  27.0     0     0      0
#  5 2017-08-26 17:40:00 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2  26.5     1     0      0
#  6 2017-08-26 17:50:00 2017-08-26 17:00:00 LCZ.3.2  26.5     1     0      0
#  7 2017-08-26 18:00:00 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.3.2  26.5     1     0      1
#  8 2017-08-26 18:10:00 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.3.2  27.0     0     1      0
#  9 2017-08-26 18:20:00 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.3.2  26.5     1     0      1
# 10 2017-08-26 18:30:00 2017-08-26 18:00:00 LCZ.3.2  26.5     1     0      1
# # ... with 40 more rows
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Time 'LCZ 3-2' 'LCZ 3-10' 'LCZ 6-1' 'LCZ 6-9' 'LCZ 9-4'
                  '2017-08-26 17:00:00'      27.5       27.5      27.5      27.0      27.0
                  '2017-08-26 17:10:00'      27.5       27.0      27.5      27.0      27.0
                  '2017-08-26 17:20:00'      27.5       27.0      27.0      27.0      27.0
                  '2017-08-26 17:30:00'      27.0       26.5      27.0      26.5      26.5
                  '2017-08-26 17:40:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.5
                  '2017-08-26 17:50:00'      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.0      26.5
                  '2017-08-26 18:00:00'      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.5
                  '2017-08-26 18:10:00'      27.0       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.0
                  '2017-08-26 18:20:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0
                  '2017-08-26 18:30:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Perhaps `OP` wants to combine `min/max/median` values for a `location` with actual date/time when min/max has occurred on that `location`. But we need to wait for his comment.

Comment: You are right. It is possible as OP did not specify the desired output.

Comment: Its always easy to find right solution once desired output is known. May be we can put a question to OP.

Comment: I think OP can read our comments. Sometimes people may not know the desired output until they see some examples. It is good that we have several different answers for the OP to review.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way of doing it with `dplyr` verbs:

```
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  gather(Location, Temp, -Time) %>%
  group_by(Date = date(Time), HoD = hour(Time), Location) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = "Temp", .funs = list(Min = min, Max = max, Median = median)) %>%
  filter(Temp == Min | Temp == Max) %>%
  arrange(Location, Time) %>%
  distinct(Temp, .keep_all = T) %>%
  mutate(MinMax = ifelse(Temp == Min, "MinTime", "MaxTime")) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Temp) %>%
  spread("MinMax", "Time")
```

**Output:**

Notice the `NA` which mean that minimum and maximum temperatures were identical on that day, in that hour and at that location.

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
# Groups:   Date, HoD, Location [10]
   Location Date         HoD   Min   Max Median MaxTime             MinTime            
   <chr>    <date>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>               <chr>              
 1 LCZ.3.10 2017-08-26    17  26.0  27.5   26.8 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017-08-26 17:50:00
 2 LCZ.3.10 2017-08-26    18  26.0  26.5   26.2 2017-08-26 18:20:00 2017-08-26 18:00:00
 3 LCZ.3.2  2017-08-26    17  26.5  27.5   27.2 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017-08-26 17:40:00
 4 LCZ.3.2  2017-08-26    18  26.5  27.0   26.5 2017-08-26 18:10:00 2017-08-26 18:00:00
 5 LCZ.6.1  2017-08-26    17  26.5  27.5   27.0 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017-08-26 17:40:00
 6 LCZ.6.1  2017-08-26    18  26.5  26.5   26.5 NA                  2017-08-26 18:00:00
 7 LCZ.6.9  2017-08-26    17  26.0  27.0   26.8 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017-08-26 17:50:00
 8 LCZ.6.9  2017-08-26    18  26.5  26.5   26.5 NA                  2017-08-26 18:00:00
 9 LCZ.9.4  2017-08-26    17  26.5  27.0   26.8 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017-08-26 17:30:00
10 LCZ.9.4  2017-08-26    18  26.0  26.5   26.0 2017-08-26 18:00:00 2017-08-26 18:10:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

Explanation: We create a new hour-`floor`ed time column `Time.hour`, by which we can group; we then calculate the necessary summary statistics.

```
res <- df %>%
    mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%  # Time as POSIXct
    gather(location, value, -Time) %>%
    mutate(Time.hour = format(Time, "%y-%m-%d %H")) %>%
    group_by(Time.hour, location) %>%
    summarise(min = min(value), max = max(value), median = median(value));
res;
## A tibble: 10 x 5
## Groups:   Time.hour [?]
#   Time.hour   location   min   max median
#   <chr>       <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 17-08-26 17 LCZ.3.10  26.0  27.5   26.8
# 2 17-08-26 17 LCZ.3.2   26.5  27.5   27.2
# 3 17-08-26 17 LCZ.6.1   26.5  27.5   27.0
# 4 17-08-26 17 LCZ.6.9   26.0  27.0   26.8
# 5 17-08-26 17 LCZ.9.4   26.5  27.0   26.8
# 6 17-08-26 18 LCZ.3.10  26.0  26.5   26.2
# 7 17-08-26 18 LCZ.3.2   26.5  27.0   26.5
# 8 17-08-26 18 LCZ.6.1   26.5  26.5   26.5
# 9 17-08-26 18 LCZ.6.9   26.5  26.5   26.5
#10 17-08-26 18 LCZ.9.4   26.0  26.5   26.0
```

If need be, convert to wide:

```
res %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    gather(what, val, min:median) %>%
    unite(key, what, location) %>%
    spread(key, val)
## A tibble: 2 x 16
#  Time.hour   max_LCZ.3.10 max_LCZ.3.2 max_LCZ.6.1 max_LCZ.6.9 max_LCZ.9.4
#  <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 17-08-26 17         27.5        27.5        27.5        27.0        27.0
#2 17-08-26 18         26.5        27.0        26.5        26.5        26.5
## ... with 10 more variables: median_LCZ.3.10 <dbl>, median_LCZ.3.2 <dbl>,
##   median_LCZ.6.1 <dbl>, median_LCZ.6.9 <dbl>, median_LCZ.9.4 <dbl>,
##   min_LCZ.3.10 <dbl>, min_LCZ.3.2 <dbl>, min_LCZ.6.1 <dbl>,
##   min_LCZ.6.9 <dbl>, min_LCZ.9.4 <dbl>
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Time 'LCZ 3-2' 'LCZ 3-10' 'LCZ 6-1' 'LCZ 6-9' 'LCZ 9-4'
 1 '2017-08-26 17:00:00'      27.5       27.5      27.5      27.0      27.0
 2 '2017-08-26 17:10:00'      27.5       27.0      27.5      27.0      27.0
 3 '2017-08-26 17:20:00'      27.5       27.0      27.0      27.0      27.0
 4 '2017-08-26 17:30:00'      27.0       26.5      27.0      26.5      26.5
 5 '2017-08-26 17:40:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.5
 6 '2017-08-26 17:50:00'      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.0      26.5
 7 '2017-08-26 18:00:00'      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.5
 8 '2017-08-26 18:10:00'      27.0       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.0
 9 '2017-08-26 18:20:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0
10 '2017-08-26 18:30:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0", header = T, row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure in which format `OP` wants results to be presented. One solution could be found using `mutate_at` as:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>% mutate(Time = ymd_hms(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Hourly = format(Time, "%Y%m%d%H")) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("LCZ")), funs(min = min, max = max, med = median )) %>%
  select(Time, Hourly, sort(names(select(.,-Time-Hourly))))
```

## Result

```
result[,1:9]
# # A tibble: 10 x 9
# # Groups: Hourly [2]
#   Time                Hourly     LCZ3_02 LCZ3_02_max LCZ3_02_med LCZ3_10 LCZ3_10_max LCZ3_10_med LCZ3_10_min
#   <dttm>              <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 2017-08-26 17:00:00 2017082617    27.5        27.5        27.2    27.5        27.5        26.8        26.0
# 2 2017-08-26 17:10:00 2017082617    27.5        27.5        27.2    27.0        27.5        26.8        26.0
# 3 2017-08-26 17:20:00 2017082617    27.5        27.5        27.2    27.0        27.5        26.8        26.0
# 4 2017-08-26 17:30:00 2017082617    27.0        27.5        27.2    26.5        27.5        26.8        26.0
# 5 2017-08-26 17:40:00 2017082617    26.5        27.5        27.2    26.5        27.5        26.8        26.0
# 6 2017-08-26 17:50:00 2017082617    26.5        27.5        27.2    26.0        27.5        26.8        26.0
# 7 2017-08-26 18:00:00 2017082618    26.5        27.0        26.5    26.0        26.5        26.2        26.0
# 8 2017-08-26 18:10:00 2017082618    27.0        27.0        26.5    26.0        26.5        26.2        26.0
# 9 2017-08-26 18:20:00 2017082618    26.5        27.0        26.5    26.5        26.5        26.2        26.0
# 10 2017-08-26 18:30:00 2017082618    26.5        27.0        26.5    26.5        26.5        26.2        26.0
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"Time    LCZ3_02    LCZ3_10   LCZ6_01   LCZ6_09    LCZ9_04
1 '2017-08-26 17:00:00'      27.5       27.5      27.5      27.0      27.0
2 '2017-08-26 17:10:00'      27.5       27.0      27.5      27.0      27.0
3 '2017-08-26 17:20:00'      27.5       27.0      27.0      27.0      27.0
4 '2017-08-26 17:30:00'      27.0       26.5      27.0      26.5      26.5
5 '2017-08-26 17:40:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.5
6 '2017-08-26 17:50:00'      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.0      26.5
7 '2017-08-26 18:00:00'      26.5       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.5
8 '2017-08-26 18:10:00'      27.0       26.0      26.5      26.5      26.0
9 '2017-08-26 18:20:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0
10 '2017-08-26 18:30:00'      26.5       26.5      26.5      26.5      26.0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```